# How do I fit an anchor tag (containing image) in bootstrap grid cell?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a 9-cell grid containing images (using bootstrap columns). The grid works fine and is responsive when it contains images only. However, my goal is to make the images clickable, hence I placed the `<img>` tag inside an anchor tag `<a>`, which resulted in the photos getting out of the grid order.

When I clicked on "Inspect" on Chrome, it showed the `<a>` as a large container, with the `<img>` centered inside of it. How do I make the `<a>` element adhere to bootstrap column sizes?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <a href="#">
          <img class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
          <img class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
          <img class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery-photo {
 object-fit: cover;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 1% 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap columns should be placed directly inside of a row.

Your links need to go inside of the bootstrap columns if you want them to be constrained by the bootstrap column sizes.

In addition, you should put `width: 100%` on your images for object-fit to work the way you want it to.

```css
.gallery-photo {
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 1% 0;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://placeimg.com/1100/750/nature" alt="something">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://placeimg.com/1100/750/nature" alt="something">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://placeimg.com/1100/750/nature" alt="something">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, that worked! I did try the width: 100% before but not when I placed the anchor and image elements within a div. Thank you so much! It worked!!!

Comment: @HaleyA Yes, I have found that unlike other HTML elements, which will constrain themselves to the width of their parent unless you specify a larger width, images have the unique tendency to display at their native width (even when that is larger than the parent container) unless you specify `width: 100%` or `max-width: 100%`

Answer (score 2):

The columns are supposed to be placed directly inside of a row.

So it should look something like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! I think I've tried this before. While the images do not exceed the specified height, they seem to be getting out of the columns, thus not forming a grid.

Comment: You have to set the width for the images.. Try it width setting the height to auto and the width to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the bootstrap columns to the `a` tag and not the `img`.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <a class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" href="#">
          <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
      </a>
      <a class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" href="#">
          <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
      </a>
      <a class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" href="#">
          <img class="gallery-photo" src="https://" alt="something">
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I think I've tried this before. While the images do not exceed the specified height, they seem to be getting out of the columns, thus not forming a grid. Do you think there are properties I can try on the anchor element in the css, with !important (to override bootstrap default properties for anchor links)?